# Where had Alexander Grothendieck been all this time?

Tags: mathematicians, grothendieck

Recently, I heard that the great **Grothendieck** has passed away (RIP). But until last year I've been aware that he is lost from the world. So how could they figure out his death? My resources on this brilliant man are too small. Any resource would be appreciated!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows insufficient prior research. The answer to this question can be found within a minute by pretty much anyone smart enough to use google.

Comment: @Danu maybe the question is off-topic, but the last part of your comment strikes me as unnecessarily harsh and close to rude.

Comment: @quid it's not meant to be rude, I'm sorry if it comes across that way. I meant it as a factual statement. I timed it, and [this took about 20 seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Grothendieck#Retirement_into_reclusion_and_death) (literally just google 'Grothendieck').

Comment: @Danu perhaps to just assert that it can be found easily using Google would have sufficed; or mentioning specifically that the information is on Wikipedia. Personally I have some sympathy for the question as there was a lot of exaggerated reports regarding "lost" over the years.

Comment: @quid note that, in particular, I was not suggesting OP is not able to use google. I was merely asserting that it was very clear that OP has not put much effort into trying to find an answer him/herself.

Comment: @Danu: I feel sorry about your opinion. What can I say else?

Comment: This question is about recent events (the person passed away 15 days ago).  I am not sure if it counts as a history question.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I'd say it's history because it talks about a long period of time, not specifically his death or the events directly leading up to his death. Whether it's suitable or not. . . That's up for debate.

Comment: If you read German, [Scharlau](http://www.scharlau-online.de/ag_1.html) wrote a nice biography of him, based partly on extensive interviews with Grothendoeck in the last few years.

Comment: @albo Which parts of Danu's opinion (actually very close to a *factual statement*, as even the discussion in the comments made clear) makes you feel "sorry"? Please be specific.

Comment: This one "anyone smart enough".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He was not "lost" in the first place; it is just that he lived a very private life after his retirement. The general public did not know where he was *exactly* but it was not at all that he was a missing person or something along these lines.

He died in a hospital, more precisely at l’hôpital de Saint-Girons (Ariège), in the south of France, near the French-Spanish boarder. This is also the general region that was named all the time for his location. Thus, the answer to the question where he was is in Ariège.

I have no information how he spent his last days, and who exactly communicated his death to the general public (and I am rather unsure this is relevant here), but the fact that he died in a hospital in a highly developed country that was moreover his home-country, shows that there is no mystery at all about his death having become known.

*Source:* [the obituary of Grothendieck in the major French newspaper Liberation](http://www.liberation.fr/sciences/2014/11/13/alexandre-grothendieck-ou-la-mort-d-un-genie-qui-voulait-se-faire-oublier_1142614) mentioned the place of his death.

Comment: Even though some "clergy-men" didn't like our discussion you were really helpful. Thanks! I think I'm gonna stop using this site. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You are welcome! It would be a pity if you stopped using the site. The comment was, as I said, in my opinion a bit harsh. But I believe Danu when he says it was not meant to hurt. We are all just trying to figure out how the site should develop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an account of his life, with many details:
http://www.ams.org/notices/200808/tx080800930p.pdf

He was not "lost". He lived in a village in the Pyrenees and did not communicate much with the rest of the world. But he did communicate with some people.